# 'public' function exposes its 'public/*package*/' parameter type SolarEdgeException

Tags: java, kotlin, package, class-visibility

I have the following Java and Kotlin classes:

```
package nl.friesoft.solaredgenotifier;

class SolarEdgeException extends Exception {
    public SolarEdgeException(String s)  {
        super(s);
    }
}



package nl.friesoft.solaredgenotifier

class SiteStorage(context: Context): ISolarEdgeListener {
    override fun onError(site: Site?, exception: SolarEdgeException?) {
    }
}
```

And I get this compilation error:

> 'public' function exposes its 'public/*package*/' parameter type SolarEdgeException

Both classes are in the same package, so why doesn't this compile?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Classes by default in Kotlin are `public`, so every member/function is exposed to the outer world. Contrarily, in Java the default visibility, that is omitting a visibility keyword such as `public`, `protected` or `private`, is `package-private`.

`SolarEdgeException` is `package-private`, while its user `SiteStorage` is entirely `public`.

That means a user of `SiteStorage` cannot catch  or use your exception at all.

---

Unfortunately Kotlin doesn't have the concept of `package-private`, because packages aren't managed the same way as in Java.

The best you can have is `internal`, which means the definition is visibile to the entire module.
I'd say, in this case, make `SolarEdgeException` a `public` class, maintaining the constructor as `package-private`.

There is a forum thread on the `package-private` visibility for Kotlin, it's an interesting read.
 [kotlin-to-support-package-protected-visibility](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-to-support-package-protected-visibility/1544)

Comment: How to fix this then? How can I make `SiteStorage` package private?

Comment: I am not sure if it is still true; but historically the Java spec didn't mandate that package layout match directory layout, this was a convention.

Comment: @Gavin you're right Gavin, I got too much used to that IDE inspection that my brain assimilated it as a compiler error. I will remove that piece of text.